# Problems with Triggers and IDENTITY_INSERT being OFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to do a process before adding data to a table using a trigger. I can do all the processes before but when I want to add the new data to the table I get a `IDENTITY_INSERT being OFF`error. I have tried turning it on at different places but then the trigger table inserted does not appear to exist:

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_remove_new_agent ON XQIAgent INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
/*SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.XQIAgent ON -This does not seem to work here */
/*Do something non related here */
INSERT INTO XQIAgent SELECT * FROM inserted /* This step does not play nicely */
```

go

Comment: Strict answer: You cannot perform a simple INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM query with IDENTITY INSERT set to on. The error generated would explain it needs explicit column definitions, and this is the case no matter where you do INSERTS (ad hoc queries, sprocs, triggers). Change the INSERT to explicitly cover all columns except the IDENTITY and change the SELECT to have those same columns in it.

Comment: The `inserted` table will have no identity value assigned to the column in an `INSTEAD OF` trigger so it makes no sense to use `IDENTITY_INSERT` here.  Specify an explicit column list on the insert statement and omit the identity column as @Dave Brown suggested and the related error will go away.

Comment: moreover setting `IDENTITY_INSERT` inside a trigger would pose security questions because alter table rights are needed to set/reset it.

Comment: Why not make this even simpler and change to an AFTER INSERT and do your "non related" stuff? That way your insert still happens and you do whatever the other stuff is you need to do.